# Attempting to strategically move the first responder in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a grid of 100 UITextFields to represent a crossword grid. Each UITextField is stored in an array called boxArray. My goal is to get the firstresponder to move to the right index when the current index is done editing.

I tried this approach:

```
var boxArray: [UITextField?] = [box00,box01,box02 .... box99] //100 index array

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let theIndex = textField.index //Attempting to get the textfield's position in it's array
    print(theIndex) //to see if I got the position (i didn't)
    //further actions will go here once index retrieved to change first responder

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return true
}
```

If I can just get the textfield's index in the array it's stored in I wouldn't have any issues coming up with the solution. I'm also going to run into another problem here that I can't access my boxArray because I don't know how to pass it into this Delegate function. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`boxArray` is a property of your class right? So you can access from any method inside the class.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if let index = boxArray.index(of: textField) {
        let next = (index + 1) % boxArray.count

        boxArray[next].becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For grid type of design you can use  `UICollectionView`. Then You can use `tab` property of `UITextField` in your `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method of  UICollectionView And later on fetch that value in your `textFieldShouldReturn`.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CollectionViewCell

        cell.textField.tag = indexPath.item

        // Rest of your code to set textField or other controls

        return cell
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let theIndex = textField.tag //Now you can get index in your array from tag property 
    print(theIndex) // This is the index which you want for further process  

    // Rest of your code
    return true
}
```

Comment: There's no mention of a collection view being used.

Comment: Yeah, but for grid type of design collection view is the most suitable control as per my opinion and that's why I have mentioned the way using which @alexstrasza can achive desired functionality.